# Symfony - migrations error: table with name "database.table" already exists

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, migration

I have the following problem in my current Symfony 6 project. I have a Many to Many Relationship between two tables in my Database. Therefore a third table for the references got created.

Afterwards, I created an Entity for this thie reference table which I needed for a query. However, if I now want to create a new migration with the command `php bin/console make:migration`.
I always get the error **"table with name "database.table" already exists"**

I think the problem occurs because, obviously the table for this entity already exists and the migration command wants to create it. But how do I solve this issue?

Thanks for any ideas in advance. :)

Comment: Do you really need to create a new entity to make your query ? I think you could make this query in one of your ManyToMany entity Repository

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to build `ManyToMany` with extra fields?
Then this is not a simple `ManyToMany` anymore: it's now a `OneToMany` + the inverse side of the `ManyToOne` relationship.

More details is here https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/many-to-many-extra-fields

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two different ManyToMany relationships, which serve different purposes, between the same two entities (Program and Participant) and used make:entity to create them.  However, the command line tool doesn't ask you for a name for the join table, so when you attempt to update the schema it uses uses the default name for both, which in this case is participant_program.

In order to resolve this you have to name at least one of the join tables explicitly, e.g.,

```
/**
     
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Program", inversedBy="enrolled_participants")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="enrolled_programs",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="participant_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="program_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    
     private $enrolled_programs;
```